# How to get new project options in a customer wizard(VS2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, createuserwizard

I'm developing a customre wizard. In my wizard, I wanna know the new project's option: add to solution? new solution or new solution and create a new directory? Doese anyone know how to do this. I'm a newbie. thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            IDictionaryEnumerator de = replacementsDictionary.GetEnumerator();
            while (de.MoveNext())
            {
                if (de.Key.ToString() == "$projectname$")
                {
                    projectName = de.Value.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Thanks
Dma